# Docker-compose ERROR [internal] booting buildkit, http: invalid Host header

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am using docker compose to create a postgresql database and a node server on a Ubuntu 23.04 VM. It was working fine for the last few weeks every time I ran `docker-compose up --build -d`. But now I have the following error:

[image: error when running docker-compose]

I tried to downgrade my docker version, but the same error persists.

Here are the docker version details:

[image: docker version]

Does anyone have an idea about what is happening?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)  Can you [edit] the question to include the Compose output in plain text (the Docker versions probably aren't interesting) and also to include a [mcve]?

Comment: Any update on this? This just cropped up this morning

Comment: i also started getting this error since yesterday.. everything used to work fine but out of blue it appeared on all containers

Comment: I also tried to use docker compose today and also facing this problem. Here's [a docker compose file and log](https://gist.github.com/timelessnesses/fe60edb9efd75a07558d1c05f3908041)

Comment: For me it was a snap/docker version problem. [Here my fix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77296158/698233)

Answer (score 76):

I recently bumped into the same error. I ran the following command

```
sudo docker compose up --build -d
```

and I get the following

```
[+] Building 17.1s (1/1) FINISHED                                                                                                                                                                          
 => ERROR [internal] booting buildkit                                                                                                                                                                17.1s
 => => pulling image moby/buildkit:buildx-stable-1                                                                                                                                                    2.4s
 => => creating container buildx_buildkit_default                                                                                                                                                    14.7s
------                                                                                                                                                                                                     
 > [internal] booting buildkit:
#0 17.14 time="2023-10-31T12:33:22Z" level=warning msg="using host network as the defaultime="2023-10-31T12:33:22Z" level=warning msg="using host network as the default"
#0 17.14 time="2023-10-31T12:33:22Z" level=warning msg="skipping containerd worker, as \"/run/containerd/containerd.sock\" does not exist"
#0 17.14 dtime="2023-10-31T12:33:22Z" level=info msg="found 1 workers, default=\"jbv801nt0swxi6eh6h1y6qgnh\""
#0 17.14 `time="2023-10-31T12:33:22Z" level=warning msg="currently, only the default worker can be used."
#0 17.14 time="2023-10-31T12:33:22Z" level=warning msg="skipping containerd worker, as \"/run/containerd/containerd.sock\" does not exist"
#0 17.14 time="2023-10-31T12:33:22Z" level=warning msg="currently, only the default worker can be used."
#0 17.14 time="2023-10-31T12:33:22Z" level=warning msg="currently, only the default worker can be used."
#0 17.14 
------
http: invalid Host header
```

After a bit of troubleshooting, it seems to be a problem with the latest stable version of Docker (20.10.24 dated 2023-10-30).

I fixed the problem by installing the latest edge version (24.0.5 dated 2023-10-07).

If you have Docker installed as a snap, you can do the following

```
sudo snap refresh docker --channel=latest/edge
```

Answer (score 15):

You can disable build kit by running it like this:

```
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0 docker-compose up --build -d
```

This is a temporary solution though. Maybe this is a bug in docker and it will be fixed (like dr.coccodrillus's answer suggests)

Answer (score 11):

This seems to be a [bug](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/11154) in a specific version of docker.

Upgrading docker might solve your problem:

`sudo snap refresh docker --channel=latest/edge`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 9):

I have to tell you that after trying so hard to download the decker version, uninstall everything and reinstall it....

In my case it was solved by running docker compose without any script.
Before I used to run like this:

> `sudo docker-compose up`

And now it works when I run:

> `sudo docker compose up`

Answer (score 8):

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 and this problem solved by:

```
sudo snap refresh docker --channel=latest/edge
```

Answer (score -4):

running with sudo worked for me:

```
sudo docker compose up
```