# Docker-compose ERROR [internal] booting buildkit, http: invalid Host header while deploy Django

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-buildkit

I'm using docker compose to create a Django server, MySQL database and Django Q on a Ubuntu 22.04.3. But when I run docker-compose -f ./docker-compose.yml up, I have the following error:

```
[+] Building 38.8s (1/1) FINISHED
 => ERROR [internal] booting buildkit                                                                             38.8s
 => => pulling image moby/buildkit:buildx-stable-1                                                                20.4s
 => => creating container buildx_buildkit_default                                                                 18.5s
------
 > [internal] booting buildkit:
#0 38.84 time="2023-10-13T13:02:28Z" level=warning msg="using host network as the deftime="2023-10-13T13:02:28Z" level=warning msg="using host network as the default"
#0 38.84 time="2023-10-13T13:02:28Z" level=warning msg="skipping containerd worker, as \"/run/containerd/containerd.sock\" does not exist"
#0 38.84 dtime="2023-10-13T13:02:28Z" level=info msg="found 1 workers, default=\"abfxoy5dnaaz4694avydedw1g\""
#0 38.84 `time="2023-10-13T13:02:28Z" level=warning msg="currently, only the default worker can be used."
#0 38.84 \time="2023-10-13T13:02:28Z" level=info msg="running server on /run/buildkit/buildkitd.sock"
#0 38.84 time="2023-10-13T13:02:28Z" level=warning msg="skipping containerd worker, as \"/run/containerd/containerd.sock\" does not exist"
#0 38.84 time="2023-10-13T13:02:28Z" level=warning msg="currently, only the default worker can be used."
#0 38.84 time="2023-10-13T13:02:28Z" level=warning msg="currently, only the default worker can be used."
#0 38.84
------
http: invalid Host header
```

My Docker info:

```
Client:
 Context:    default
 Debug Mode: false
 Plugins:
  buildx: Docker Buildx (Docker Inc., v0.10.4)
  compose: Docker Compose (Docker Inc., v2.17.2)

Server:
 Containers: 1
  Running: 1
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 0
 Images: 4
 Server Version: 20.10.24
 Storage Driver: zfs
  Zpool: rpool
  Zpool Health: ONLINE
  Parent Dataset: rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_5bq6zk/var/snap
  Space Used By Parent: 1548288
  Space Available: 502181703680
  Parent Quota: no
  Compression: lz4
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: systemd
 Cgroup Version: 2
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: io.containerd.runc.v2 io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: 2806fc1057397dbaeefbea0e4e17bddfbd388f38
 runc version:
 init version: de40ad0
 Security Options:
  apparmor
  seccomp
   Profile: default
  cgroupns
 Kernel Version: 5.19.0-46-generic
 Operating System: Ubuntu Core 22
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 1
 Total Memory: 7.752GiB
 Name: COSHOKDS01
 ID: CRI6:RNK6:QDAX:DPRN:OTB6:MEWS:OKKV:4J7W:LPPW:5T5G:VC6N:2PN3
 Docker Root Dir: /var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker
 Debug Mode: false
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false
```

And my Dockerfile is as follow:

```
FROM python 3.10

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install python3-dev default-libmysqlclient-dev -y

RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN pip install pip -U

COPY requirements.txt /app/

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . /app/
```

My docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: rest
    container_name: rest
    restart: always
    command: python manage.py runserver 10.36.0.149:8000
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    depends_on:
      - mysql
      - django_q
  mysql:
    image: mysql
    container_name: mysql
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password --mysqlx=0
    volumes:
      - "./mysql:/var/lib/mysql"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_HOST=localhost
      - MYSQL_PORT=3306
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=kds_db
      - MYSQL_USER=kds_admin
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    restart: always
  django_q:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py qcluster
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    depends_on:
      - redis
```

Would anyone have an idea about what is happening?

Thank you very much

I try to reinstall my docker and avoid using BuildKit, but they don't work. I want to deploy the Django REST service and Django Q on docker.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have the same problem. I guess you are using a snap docker.
The (snap) docker version (2904) on my server has the same problem.

On my laptop the docker version (2893) is working as expected.
I changed the snap channel on my laptop to latest/candidate (2904) and the
same problem occurs. Switched back to latest/stable and everything is fine again.

So:

```
snap info docker
```

to get some version info.

Use:

```
snap refresh --stable docker
```

to switch to the stable channel.

now your project build on my laptop as to be expected.
I did have to change:

```
FROM python 3.10
```

to

```
FROM python:3.10
```

The switching works on my laptop (Ubuntu 23.10), but not on my server (Ubuntu 18.04.6).

On the server i had to use:

```
sudo snap refresh --revision=2893 docker
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I change the docker, and the error never shows up now.

Comment: on the server i had to 'pin' the correct version of docker by: snap  refresh --hold=forever docker

Comment: If you can indicate my answer as 'correct' i would apreciate

Answer (score 0):

You can also run docker compose exec web /bin/bash
then navigate to the respective directory and start executing normal commands. For example, I have a Django container running, the docker compose exec web /bin/bash will allow me to cd/path/django_project and then executes commands under manage.py utility